# Joins without foreign key

Tags: mysql, sql

In case of following tables:

```
x, y, lat, lng
```

And table

```
lat, lng, Country, State, City
```

Now, I need to have first table with all the values, including lat and lng. On the other hand, data in second table does not need to exist, it's only a possible extension.

You can see that there is sort of parent-child relation between first and second table, so I'm considering using lat, lng as foreign key as I'm going to make joins. On the other hand, everything except lat and lng does not need to exist.

Should I use foreign keys, or not? Maybe work without them, but still join to be able to filter on rest of data (country, state, city)?

Comment: If it is mandatory that lat,lng in 2nd table should only contain values that are currently presents in 1st table,then the foreign key is required. Otherwise, you can work with left join between 1st and 2nd table.

Comment: you could join on both lat and lng to make it unique

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes and no depending on how data gets in to those tables.

Yes, if records in the second table will always be created after the first (ie the second tables data is some information that will come later)

No, if data in the second table will be coming in independently of the first (eg the first table is being filled by a user and the second is getting filled by a gis data import)...if this is the case, indexing both tables on long and lat will be enough to alleviate query performance hits.